# How to do hooks in Clojure

Tags: clojure, hook

I have a situation where I am creating and destroying objects in one clojure namespace, and want another namespace to co-ordinate. However I do not want the first namespace to have to call the second explicitly on object destruction.

In Java, I could use a listener. Unfortunately the underlying java libraries do not signal events on object destruction. If I were in Emacs-Lisp, then I'd use hooks which do the trick.

Now, in clojure I am not so sure. I have found the Robert Hooke library https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke. But this is more like defadvice in elisp terms -- I am composing functions. More over the documentation says:

"Hooks are meant to extend functions you don't control; if you own the target function there are obviously better ways to change its behaviour."

Sadly, I am not finding it so obvious.

Another possibility would be to use add-watch, but this is marked as alpha.

Am I missing another obvious solution?

Example Added:

So First namespace....

```
(ns scratch-clj.first
   (:require [scratch-clj.another]))

(def listf (ref ()))

(defn add-object []
  (dosync
    (ref-set listf (conj
               @listf (Object.))))
  (println listf))


(defn remove-object []
  (scratch-clj.another/do-something-useful (first @listf))
  (dosync
     (ref-set listf (rest @listf)))
  (println listf))


(add-object)
(remove-object)
```

Second namespace

```
(ns scratch-clj.another)


(defn do-something-useful [object]
   (println "object removed is:" object))
```

The problem here is that scratch-clj.first has to require another and explicitly push removal events across. This is a bit clunky, but also doesn't work if I had "yet-another" namespace, which also wanted to listen.

Hence I thought of hooking the first function.

Comment: Hmm, be careful about the term "destruction". I believe object destruction only occurs when the GC cleans up. Removing objects is different to destroying objects, though one may cause the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this solution suitable to your requirements?

scratch-clj.first:

```
(ns scratch-clj.first)

(def listf (atom []))
(def destroy-listeners (atom []))
(def add-listeners (atom []))

(defn add-destroy-listener [f]
  (swap! destroy-listeners conj f))

(defn add-add-listener [f]
  (swap! add-listeners conj f))

(defn add-object []
  (let [o (Object.)]
   (doseq [f @add-listeners] (f o))
   (swap! listf conj o)
   (println @listf)))

(defn remove-object []
  (doseq [f @destroy-listeners] (f (first @listf)))
  (swap! listf rest)
  (println @listf))
```

Some listeners:

```
(ns scratch-clj.another
  (:require [scratch-clj.first :as fst]))

(defn do-something-useful-on-remove [object]
  (println "object removed is:" object))

(defn do-something-useful-on-add [object]
  (println "object added is:" object))
```

Init binds:

```
(ns scratch-clj.testit
  (require [scratch-clj.another :as another]
           [scratch-clj.first :as fst]))

(defn add-listeners []
  (fst/add-destroy-listener another/do-something-useful-on-remove)
  (fst/add-add-listener another/do-something-useful-on-add))

(defn test-it []
  (add-listeners)
  (fst/add-object)
  (fst/remove-object))
```

test:

```
(test-it)
=> object added is: #<Object java.lang.Object@c7aaef>
   [#<Object java.lang.Object@c7aaef>]
   object removed is: #<Object java.lang.Object@c7aaef>
   ()
```

Comment: Yes, I think it does. I think I could do this with watches as well, but this seems a bit more natural to me, as well as being more general. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot like what you're describing is callbacks.

Something like:

```
(defn make-object 
  [destructor-fn] 
  {:destructor destructor-fn :other-data "data"})

(defn destroy-object
  [obj]
  ((:destructor obj) obj))

; somewhere at the calling code...

user> (defn my-callback [o] (pr [:destroying o]))
#'user/my-callback
user> (destroy-object (make-object my-callback))
[:destroying {:destructor #<user$my_callback user$my_callback@73b8cdd5>, :other-data "data"}]
nil
user>
```

Comment: That's a reasonable idea, but it just shifts the problem. Now I need to be able to hook into my make-object function, so I can add a destructor. Take the example above (added after your comment, sorry!)-- object creation and destruction is happening in namespace "first" while my callback equivalent is elsewhere.

Comment: Well, stated like that, one of the problems is that clojure doesn't really play that well with the idea of objects having destructors. You'll generally have a nicer time if you regard (almost) all of your objects as "dumb" records. From your code you don't want to see if the object is destroyed, you want to do some kind of action any time the collection in listf is modified. Watches are the obvious tool for this and they're not likely to be removed any time soon.

Comment: In this case, the objects in question (like in my example) are Java objects -- I am using clojure to manipulate a Java API. Once removed from the list, the objects will be destroyed. A reference watch is guaranteed to be called? It's not vetoable is it?

Answer (score 0):

So, here is my final solution following mobytes suggestion. A bit more work, but 
I suspect that I will want this in future.

Thanks for all the help

```
;; hook system
(defn make-hook []
  (atom []))

(defn add-hook [hook func]
  (do
    (when-not
        (some #{func} @hook)
      (swap! hook conj func))
    @hook))

(defn remove-hook [hook func]
  (swap! hook
         (partial
          remove #{func})))

(defn clear-hook [hook]
  (reset! hook []))

(defn run-hook
  ([hook]
      (doseq [func @hook] (func)))
  ([hook & rest]
      (doseq [func @hook] (apply func rest))))

(defn phils-hook []
  (println "Phils hook"))

(defn phils-hook2 []
  (println "Phils hook2"))


(def test-hook (make-hook))
(add-hook test-hook phils-hook)
(add-hook test-hook phils-hook2)
(run-hook test-hook)
(remove-hook test-hook phils-hook)
(run-hook test-hook)
```